# How to write \n inside the \code{} in latex

Tags: latex

I am trying to write a code inside \code{} in .tex file.
I am eager to write

```
 \code{
      cat("\n I want to write like this!")
      }
```

However, latex gives me ERROR message, saying that \n is undefined control sequence.

I also tried `\code{$\n$}` and `\code{\\n}`. Neither works.
(I also know that \n works in verbatim environment. But I HAVE TO use `\code{}`)

Answer (score 12):

You can try this..

```
\textbackslash n
```